# Opening popups in jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 after a page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I know this gets asked again and again and I've partially solved it with other answers. I'm stuck now though.

I'm using popups for a tour of an app. The order of events is:
1. Press "Next" button.
2. Close popup
3. Change page
4. Open new popup

You can't chain popups so I'm using afterclose. It works fine for the first transition but after that I get no popup. The console.log in this code gives output.

```
$('#introPanel1Next').click(function(){
  $('#introPanel1').popup({
    afterclose: function(){
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page2", {
        transition: "slide"
      }).on( "pagecontainershow", function() {
        $('#introPanel2').popup('open');
      });
    }
  }).popup('close');
});

$('#introPanel2Next').click(function(){
  $('#introPanel2').popup({
    afterclose: function(){
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page3", {
        transition: "slide"
    }).on( "pagecontainershow", function() {
        $('#introPanel3').popup('open');
      });
    }
  }).popup('close');
});
```

So I can go from page1 to page2 and have a popup, but even though I can go to page3 introPanel3 does not pop-up.

I thought it might be the event I was listening for (e.g. pagecontainershow) but I've tried them all. Some of them don't give a pop-up on page2 since the page needs to finish loading before the popup("open") is called.

I don't understand why it works for the first transition and popup but not the next (and thus subsequent ones, 5 in total).

---

With regards to an answer below, I've tried this:

```
$('#introPanel1Next').click(function(){
  $('#introPanel1').popup({
    afterclose: function(){
      $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page2", {
        transition: "slide"
      }).on( "pagecontainershow", function() {
        $('#introPanel2', ui.toPage).popup("open");          
      });
    }
  }).popup('close');
});
```

It doesn't work. :(

Comment: You should probably only define the pagecontainershow event once outside of the click handlers and then check the ui.toPage/ui.prevPage to decide which popup to show.  Also it would help to see your HTML. Where are the popup panels in relation to the pages, etc? Maybe a fiddle?

Comment: because whenever `pagecontainershow` fires, it will open `$('#introPanel2').popup('open');`.

Comment: `function (e, ui)` you forgot `e, ui`.

Comment: I've added that. Still the same.

Answer (score 3):

When `pagecontainershow` fires the first time, it will open `#introPanel2`. Afterward, you close that *popup* and bind another `pagecontainershow` to open a different *popup* `#introPanel3`.

Upon moving to page 3, `pagecontainershow` will fire, but it will try to open `#introPanel2` and then `#introPanel3`. The result, none of them is open.

You need to check which page is active in order to determine which popup to open. e.g.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
   var activePage = ui.toPage; /* as of jQM 1.4.3 */
   var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"); /* 1.4.2 and before */

   if (activePage[0].id == "page1") {
      $("#popup1").popup("open")
   }
});
```

Or, just find *popup* inside active page and open it.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
   $(".ui-popup", ui.toPage).popup("open");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/QxxH4/)**

Comment: Can you show me how I do it with your second solution with my code? Do I put, for example, #introPanel2, in place of .ui-popup? Because I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: if you want to specify a popup, you will need to check page ID. The second solution is easier because it opens a popup with the active page. If you have many popups, you can target a specific popup with a specific class, e.g. `$(".ui-popup.foo", ui.toPage).popup("open");` This will open a popup with class `foo` in active page regardless which page is currently shown @SubjectiveEffect

Comment: Can I do this with the pop-up ids? They all have unique ids but not unique classes.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Yes you can, for example `$("#popup1, #popup2, #popup3", ui.toPage).popup("open");` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/k3mZF/

Comment: PS. Your fiddle doesn't do anything for me at all. I'm using Chrome. The result is just gray bar with "Page 1" at the top. Nothing else happens, clicking anywhere does nothing, there are no popups.

Comment: @subjective hit run and try again. I'm using chrome and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to reload it. Still not working for me. I can get the readout from a console log that shows me I'm getting into the .on( "pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) bit but the popup just isn't coming up. No errors in the console.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect sometimes you need to delay `setTimeout` running code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/k3mZF/1/

Comment: Yeah, I was using this previously with a 500ms delay. It makes it very slow though. Using afterclose to chain popups on one page is really much smoother, which is why I wanted to do it for the rest of the code. I've been trying setTimeout with your suggestion but that hasn't worked either. It's very odd. I've put my code in JSHint and it seems fine.